# Web service to run perl script remotely/periodically

Tags: perl, cron, hosting, web-hosting, vps

I was looking for a service paid/free which will enable me to run my Perl script(which has a considerable run time) remotely through a web interface or run it periodically like a cron job. Is there anything like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just buy some VPS (Virtual Private Server) hosting plan.

A VPS Web hosting plan means you share the physical server hardware with other websites, but you are allocated a dedicated slice of the system resources.

With VPS you can configure your own cron jobs, install Perl libraries, execute Perl scripts, ... all with your own root.

There are many VPS hosting providers. Google for them. For example $6.00 per month will give you a basic Linux VPS with [Interserver.Net](http://www.interserver.net/vps/).